# Rails - TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string, when updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to update an attribute. It's a boolean with a default of false. In my method I make a query to find the right user. then I try to update that user by flipping the `owner boolean` to true. It's a really strange error I'm getting because it's updating the method but it also sending out this error `TypeError: nil is not a symbol nor a string`

I'm just wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

### Controller

```
def update
  membership = current_account.account_memberships.find_by(user_id: params[:id])
  membership.update(owner: true)
end
```

### HTML

```
<%= link_to "Owner", account_membership_path(user), {
  class: "icon icon-owner-upgrade",
  method: :patch,
} %>
```

Comment: Check if the `membership` is `nil`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are trying to update the record in a dependent model, it possibly has only a foreign key, but no primary key. The problem can be solved if you add a line `self.primary_key` like this:

```
class YourDependentRecord < ApplicationRecord  
  self.primary_key = 'user_id'
end
```

where `'user_id'` is the primary key in the master model.

Comment: great! I met this problem when using a oracle database with not-rails-flavor database ( primary key is not "id") .  thanks a lot!